# how to have one onsuccess call for multiple ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a problem in which I have to call multiple AJAX requests, and I want to write a callback which will be called only once when all of them are completed. I can have multiple ajax calls so I may not like to chain those Ajax calls in the callbacks of the previous callback as happened [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2576390/1823389).

So I tried something like this -

```
var requestCompletedArray = [];

/* assuming i have `n` ajax calls to make */
for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    ajaxCall(/* some url, data etc */, callback);
}

/* my callback definition */
function callback(data) {
    if(requestCompletedArray.length < n-1) {
        requestCompletedArray.push(data.status);
        return;
    } else if(requestCompletedArray.length === n-1) {
        //do something, all requests are completed
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

I am not feeling good about this solution. What does you all think about it? If it is not a good solution, can I have some good suggestions for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1) take a look  at $.when in jquery documentation

or

2) if you don't want to use it you might want to do something like:

- implement custom object that holds the number of ajax requests sent
- make an instance in global scope
- provice instance with allFinished callback
- make each ajax response callback decrease number by 1
- when number of reaches 0 > run allFinished callback

Comment: Thanks, But i cant use jQuery. For the second solution of yours, it looks pretty much like what i tried.